# Why do I need to delete the META-INF folder when installing mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In Minecraft, nearly every tutorial on how to install a MOD tells you to remove the META-INF folder. However none of the ones I found tell you what it is. I don't like the idea of deleting a folder without knowing what it is or what it does.

So what is the META-INF folder, and why should I delete it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because Minecraft is digitally signed. META-INF contains a signature file (`.SF`) that accounts for all the files within the JAR and their checksums, and Mojang's actual signature (`.RSA`).

When that signature checks out, you know it wasn't tampered with and comes from the source that signed it (in this case, Mojang). When you *do* tamper with it by installing mods, the signature becomes invalid and Minecraft won't start at all.

By deleting the META-INF directory, you remove the signature completely. Depending on your security settings, you might get an "unknown publisher" warning, but you'll be able to run it.

More detailed info: [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)

Comment: Ah, one of those other properties, the big one.

Comment: Better copy it from there,instead of deleting.