# What do I do if I don't have a META-INF folder or minecraft.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have looked all over the Internet for solutions but I have got nothing.

I want to install the minepainter mod but I need a META-INF folder and a minecraft.jar.

Comment: Well, first, it's meta-inf and minecraft.jar. Does that help at all?

Comment: You'll find `minecraft.jar` in `%appdata%\.minecraft\bin` in Windows. To get there, hold the `⊞ Windows Key` and press `R`. Then, type in the above folder and press enter. Locate `minecraft.jar`, right-click it, and choose to `Open With` → WinRAR.

Comment: Or 7zip, depending on which one you have installed.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27015/why-do-i-need-to-delete-the-meta-inf-folder-when-installing-mods

Comment: [A basic guide on how to install mods](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/124583-guide-how-to-install-mods-for-minecraft/) may be useful to read too.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125601/i-cant-find-the-bin-folder-in-my-minecraft-folder

Answer (score 9):

### In 1.5.2 and earlier:

`minecraft.jar` is located in `%appdata%\.minecraft\bin`, and can be opened using many archive readers (such as 7zip, Jzip, WinRAR, etc.) as Schism mentioned. `META-INF` should be contained within this `.jar`. However, if `META-INF` **is not** in the `.jar`, you shouldn't need to worry about it, as the addition of mods requires it to be removed anyways. If you have installed mods in the past, you should have removed it then. It can also be removed by third-party tools such as MCPatcher.

### In 1.6 and later:

There is no `minecraft.jar` anymore since the launcher has moved to a version-based system. The equivalent to `minecraft.jar` is now something like:

```
%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\<x.y.z>\<x.y.z>.jar
```

... where `x.y.z` is the version of Minecraft you are running and trying to mod. Modding Minecraft now is the same as before, except you're changing that `x.y.z.jar` file instead of `minecraft.jar`: open that `x.y.z.jar` file, place the mod's files as usual, and delete the `META-INF` folder before saving `x.y.z.jar`.