# I can't find the bin folder in my .minecraft folder!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to get mods on my minecraft but the folder isn't there and so I can't get to my minecraft.jar folder... and I even looked in the version folder where someone told me the bin folder would be and it wasn't there. is there any way to get the bin folder so I can get to the minecraft.jar folder?

Comment: There is no bin folder anymore. See this question's answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114431/what-do-i-do-if-i-dont-have-a-meta-inf-folder-or-minecraft-jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any version higher than 1.5.2, your jars will be located in `.minecraft > versions > (version) > (version).jar`. So if you are using 1.6.2, you will want to mod `.minecraft > versions > 1.6.2 > 1.6.2.jar`.

In case you are wondering why you don't have a bin file - it was only used in versions 1.5.2 and below. The new Minecraft launcher doesn't use or create a bin file - it will only be there if you played Minecraft versions 1.5.2 and below.

Comment: Try not to answer questions that are clear duplicates. It just encourages people to post duplicate questions.

Comment: The question linked to sucks and should be rewritten.

Comment: @James Go nuts with the editing then. This is still a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know...